# Randomly inconsistent height returned by Javascript in Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

I am working on a web app, visible [here](https://pub.phyks.me/tmp/VelibFxOS/#station-0).

On desktops, I don't have any problems. However, in Firefox for Android, `$('#station-'+id).height()` takes two values, and it seems to be one of the two, at random.

I can't find why I have such inconsistent behavior… It only happens in Firefox for Android (but I only tested desktop browsers and Firefox for Android).

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with screen.height, changing it to screen.innerHeight fixed it. I don't know if this approach is going to work on any element on the page though. Note that you'll have to subtract the padding values if you want to convert the innerHeight to the height.